# How to get current browser timezone, ip address in angular 2?

Tags: angular, browser, timezone

We need the client browser ip address and timezone in angular 2. Any npm plugin available. No need to use any other URL to get the information.

Answer (score 3):

To determine the timezone you can use the [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object in the browser, it's supported in all modern browsers and IE11.

```
if (typeof Intl === 'object' && typeof Intl.DateTimeFormat === 'function') {
  // get timezone string from Intl object
  console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
}
```

You won't be able to determine the public IP address on the client side without sending a request to a server. You could use a third party service like [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/) or [ipify.org](https://www.ipify.org/). Alternatively you can create your own private service on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP address use this package: [IP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip)

Use the IP address to get the timezone using this package: [Satelite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/satelize)